# How to configure Reporting server on SQL Server 2008, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, ssrs, reporting

I want to configure reporting server on sql server 2008.I m using Windows 7
 Operating System  .  I configure reporting manager using Reporting Services Configuration Manager and provide Service Account , Web Service Url, Execution Account and Report Manager Url setting .

But When i click on link of Report Server Web Service Url (`http://udham-pc/TestReportServer`), it ask for credentials I provide 
OS user credentials. Then it opens page with following error

```
The permissions granted to user 'udham-PC\udham' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help
```

And when I click the Report Manager URl(`http://udham-pc/TestReports`) , then it redirects to `http://udham-pc/TestReports/Pages/Folder.aspx`.  But the page Opened is Only Having Header(On left side

```
SQL Server Reporting Services
Home
```

and on right side of header three links

```
Home | My Subscriptions | Help
```

) no content on page.

I think i am missing some configuration.
Please let me know. With prior thanks

Answer (score 0):

The report server by default does not have any reports.  What you are seeing is the listing of  the files on the server, in this case there are none.

However, the other issue you may be having is that you have not setup your user account to have full admin rights on the server.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms253091%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is related to TFS integration but you can simply swap out the `application-tier` with your report server name.  Remember you need to do this from the report server the first time, using administrator credentials.

Other than that everything appears to be working properly.